# Is there a way to get js display data using the requests python module?

Tags: javascript, python, html

So I am trying to access data on a video game stat tracker website.  Now when I go to inspect element on the website and look at the code it says:

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">Division 7</div>
```

But when I use requests.get(url).text the same element shows up as:

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">{{ activeArena.division.metadata.description }}</div>
```

I am trying to get the "Division 7" part but keep getting this activeArena thing, I am using python, the code I have tried is

```
import requests
url = ('https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/tl%20starrlol/competitive?season=16')
file = open("myfilename", "w")
r = requests.get(url)
info = r.content
info = str(info)
file.write(info)
file.close()
```

and I have also tried

```
import requests
url = ('https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/tl%20starrlol/competitive?season=16')
file = open("myfilename", "w")
r = requests.get(url)
info = r.text
file.write(info)
file.close()
```

I am pretty new to coding so if the answer is obvious I apologize, but I am lost.

Comment: It looks like they're using mustache or another templating engine. You likely need to execute the JavaScript on the page so it can fill in that data. Selenium or Pyppeteer can be used for that, although they complicate matters a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you're receiving contains a template engine code, the javascript on the page is loading and filling it up with values. If you examine the page via the network panel on the browser you'll notice a stats API call. Make the same call from your code to extract the data you need.

```py
import requests

url = "https://fortnitetracker.com/api/v0/profile/863f1c3c-2e61-487e-8987-ceefff2981ad/stats"
querystring = {"season":"16","isCompetitive":"true"}
response = requests.request("GET", url, data="", headers={}, params=querystring)

data = response.json()
print (data[0]['arena']['division']['displayValue'])

# prints "Contender League Division 7"
```

It's better to check for official APIs instead of this approach. The parameters in the API like the UUID after profile may be a parameter that's valid only for a certain time. It's also worth evaluating the Selenium or Puppeteer approach recommended in the comments(under the question) to see if that fits your overall problem.